# Get PyInstaller to import Basemap

Tags: python, pyinstaller, matplotlib-basemap

I'm working on building a standalone executable for a simple tool I built that uses Basemap.  (Using Python 2.7, using the dev version of PyInstaller - 2.1).  The .exe (single file) builds just fine, but when it runs, I get the following error:

```
Traceback <most recent call last>:
  File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller-2.1dev_-py2.7.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec<bytecode, module.__dict>
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\MYNAME\Python code\Flood\src\root\nested\build\FloodRisk\out00-PYZ.pyz\mpl_toolkits.basemap", line 30, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller-2.1dev_-py2.7.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", in load_module
    exec<bytecode, module.__dict__>
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\MYNAME\My Documents\Python code\Flood\src\root\nested\build\FloodRisk\out00-PYZ.pyz\mpl_toolkits.basemap.pyproj", line 242, in <module>
IOError: proj data directory not found. Expecting it at: C:\DOCUME~1\MYNAME\LOCALS~1\Temp\_MEI68362\mpl_toolkits\basemap\data
```

Anyone have any luck getting Basemap to load properly into a single .exe file built using PyInstaller?  I'm building using a very simple batch file:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-develop\PyInstaller\main.py" --onefile "C:\Documents and Settings\MYNAME\My Documents\Python code\Flood\src\root\nested\FloodRisk.py"
pause
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took me a few days, but I think I sorted it from piecing together a few partial solutions:

From http://www.jontrinder.com/blog/?paged=2 :

In pyproj.py, found in C:...\Lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap
Just past the huge lists is a line that looks something like

```
pyproj_datadir = os.sep.join([os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data'])
```

Replace that with

```
if 'PROJ_DIR' in os.environ:
    pyproj_datadir = os.environ['PROJ_DIR']
else:
    pyproj_datadir = os.sep.join([os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data'])
```

The piece that was missing from the linked solution was then adding the data path when actually running PyInstaller with --paths

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-develop\PyInstaller\main.py" --onefile --paths="C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\*" "C:\Documents and Settings\KAHERE\My Documents\Python code\Flood\src\root\nested\FloodRisk.py"
pause
```

Just thought I'd post in case anyone else was banging their head on this one.

Comment: For future reference : the link you posted leads to the home page of the blog. I think the specific post you were referring to is : [_**Pyinstaller, Matplotlib and BaseMap**_](http://www.jontrinder.com/blog/?p=348)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is tell PyInstaller to add the basemap data to the distribution. Here is some sample code. Assuming that you have an ortho.py file in directory E:\scratch, put the following ortho.spec in the same directory and run it as

```
PyInstaller -y ortho.spec
```

Here is ortho.spec:

```
a = Analysis(['ortho.py'],
             pathex=['E:\\scratch'],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=None,
             runtime_hooks=None)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='ortho.exe',
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=True )

import mpl_toolkits.basemap
import os

src_basedata = os.path.join(mpl_toolkits.basemap.__path__[0], "data")
tgt_basedata = os.path.join('mpl_toolkits', 'basemap', 'data')

coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas + Tree(src_basedata, prefix=tgt_basedata),
               strip=None,
               upx=True,
               name='ortho')
```