# Import Basemap fails under Fedora 21

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I installed python-basemap and python-basemap-data (and all its dependencies, e.g. pyproj) but I am unable to import Basemap in a simple Python program, because of this error:

```
$ python mapper.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mapper.py", line 4, in <module>
    from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from mpl_toolkits.basemap import pyproj
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/pyproj.py", line 241, in <module>
    raise IOError(msg)
IOError: proj data directory not found. Expecting it at: /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data
```

I tried the solution (replacing the code snippet) from here: [Get PyInstaller to import Basemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749296/get-pyinstaller-to-import-basemap), but this does not work either.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked that the install of the data happened to the correct subdirectory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Fedora 20, /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/pyproj.py had the line:

```
pyproj_datadir = '/usr/share/basemap'
```

In Fedora 21 the data directory has been changed to:

```
pyproj_datadir = os.sep.join([os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data'])
```

In Fedora 21, pyproj.py is looking for the data in 
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data, but the rpm packages for python-basemap-data and python-basemap-data-hires are still putting the proj data in /usr/share/basemap.  Until this gets fixed, I found two workarounds:

1. Create the directoy /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data and copy the data from /usr/share/basemap into that new directory, or
2. Edit the file pyproj.py and change the line

.

```
pyproj_datadir = os.sep.join([os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data'])
```

to

```
pyproj_datadir = '/usr/share/basemap'
```

Comment: Thank you for this complete answer! Solution 1) works flawlessly. Solution 2) fails, because it still cannot find some epsg codes. Let's hope the fix comes soon too avoid such workarounds.